# tmux doesn't passes correctly ctrl-shift-arrow sequences

Tags: terminal, keyboard-shortcuts, keyboard, tmux

Tmux doesn't passes correctly the ctrl-shift-arrow sequences.
It doesn't work on emacs, and when I use `sed -n l`, I see it displays the escape sequence of the arrow key alone instead of the full sequnce

For example, ctrl-shift-right passes as `^[[C` (which is the same as the escape sequence of the right key), instead of `^[OC` (outside tmux).

Any idea of how to solve this?
Note that ctrl-arrow key (without shift) and shift-arrow (without ctrl) pass correctly.

My .tmux.conf is:

```
# Changes prefix from Ctrl-b to Alt-a
unbind C-b
set -g prefix M-a

set-option -g default-terminal "xterm-256color"




# choosing windows with Alt-#
bind -n M-0 select-window -t 0
bind -n M-1 select-window -t 1
bind -n M-2 select-window -t 2
bind -n M-3 select-window -t 3
bind -n M-4 select-window -t 4
bind -n M-5 select-window -t 5
bind -n M-6 select-window -t 6
bind -n M-7 select-window -t 7
bind -n M-8 select-window -t 8
bind -n M-9 select-window -t 9


setw -g monitor-activity on
set -g visual-activity on

set-window-option -g window-status-current-bg white

set -g mode-mouse on
set -g mouse-resize-pane on
set -g mouse-select-pane on
set -g mouse-select-window on


# Toggle mouse on
bind m \
    set -g mode-mouse on \;\
    set -g mouse-resize-pane on \;\
    set -g mouse-select-pane on \;\
    set -g mouse-select-window on \;\
    display 'Mouse: ON'

# Toggle mouse off
bind M \
    set -g mode-mouse off \;\
    set -g mouse-resize-pane off \;\
    set -g mouse-select-pane off \;\
    set -g mouse-select-window off \;\
    display 'Mouse: OFF'

# disable selecting panes with mouse (because enabling mess with copy-paste)
set-option -g mouse-select-pane off


# display status bar message for 4 sec
set-option -g display-time 4000


# Start windows and panes at 1, not 0
set -g base-index 1
set -g pane-base-index 1


# enable shift-arrow keys
set-window-option -g xterm-keys on

# start default shell
set-option -g default-shell $SHELL

# support for escape char for vi
set -s escape-time 0
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like `tmux` is doing the right thing for your example:

> For example, ctrl-shift-right passes as `^[[C` (which is the same as the escape sequence of the right key), instead of `^[OC` (outside tmux).

because the usual connotation of that sequence is that it is the same as cursor-movement sent from the host.  A *zero* parameter is the same as a missing parameter, which happens to be *one*.

The terminal was not identified; `xterm` does not do that.  For <kbd>control</kbd><kbd>shift</kbd><kbd>right-arrow</kbd>, `xterm` may send `^[[1;6C`.  In this case, `tmux` absorbs the escape sequence sent, because it is not in the table of known xterm-style keys that it knows about.  In `tmux`, the file `xterm-keys.c` contains a table, with the comment:

```
/*                                                     
 * xterm-style function keys append one of the following values before the last
 * character:
 *
 * 2 Shift
 * 3 Alt
 * 4 Shift + Alt                               
 * 5 Ctrl
 * 6 Shift + Ctrl
 * 7 Alt + Ctrl
 * 8 Shift + Alt + Ctrl
 *
 * Rather than parsing them, just match against a table.
 *
 * There are three forms for F1-F4 (\\033O_P and \\033O1;_P and \\033[1;_P).
 * We accept any but always output the latter (it comes first in the table).
 */
```